# What is the best way to convert a string to UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, string-conversion

I am wondering what the best way to convert an string into UTF-8 using PHP is.

The following looks ok on the page, but in MySQL some characters are looking garbled.

- *MYSQL*: `UPGRADE EVENT â€“ New Mazda2 from Â£124.99 per month. Representative 0% APR over 3 years. Min 50% deposit required. Call xxxxxxxxxxxx for test drive, info or Ts&Cs.`
- *ON PAGE*: `UPGRADE EVENT - New Mazda2 from £124.99 per month. Representative 0% APR over 3 years. Min 50% deposit required. Call xxxxxxxxxxxx for test drive, info or Ts&Cs.`

I have looked at iconv, mb_string, html_entity_decode, htmlentities, mb_convert_encoding etc..

The database collation is utf8_unicode_ci and the tables' charset is utf8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Character Encoding Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926823/character-encoding-problem)

Comment: mb_convert_encoding worked for me, what problems are you facing?

Comment: @Tobiask: mb_convert_encoding(htmlentities(html_entity_decode($string), ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1'),  "UTF-8", "UTF-8"); is what i use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'")` (or `dbh->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'")`) to set the encoding of the connection.

Comment: SET NAMES 'utf8' doesnt seem to work.

if($this->dbh->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'")) {
 if($this->dbh->exec("INSERT INTO .....")) {
  //do stuff
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

You should alos set encoding of mysql connection. Try to use `SET NAMES utf8`